# NDK command line parameters in eclipse

Tags: android-ndk

When building a `NativeActivity` project using the command line, I can pass additional parameters to `ndk-build` such as `-j 4` or `-B`.

Is there a way I can set it so those same parameters will be passed when I run a build through eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do the above. First, you need CDT plugins installed for eclipse. If you are using eclipse from `Android-adt-bundle` then the eclipse comes pre-installed with CDT plugins.

Second, in the preferences you need to set the ndk path as shown below:

```
Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> Android -> NDK -> set path to the NDK
```

Third,

```
Right click on an Android project and select Android Tools -> Add native support.
```

Fourth,

```
    Right click project -> properties -> C/C++ Build:

    In the build command, you will be having ndk-build, now append that command wit whatever parameter you want to pass. Then press apply and press ok.
```